# Kappa value to MSE

Tags: statistics

I have performance measure in kappa value, lets say that the result is: $0.57$

I need to convert this number $(0.57)$ to MSE (Mean Square Error).

How can I do that?

(MSE to Kappa value will also be a good answer)

I tried to find online and also tried to convert it myself but i'm don't think i got it correctly.

Comment: I don't see how there could be a direct conversion function. Wouldn't it depend on how many categories your raters can select from and how you measure the "error" when they don't agree? Perhaps your question would be clearer if you described what you're doing in more detail, for example what the data were from which you got $\kappa = 0.57.$